# Select i3 window manager in Xubuntu 21.10 but the OS is identified as Ubuntu 21.10 instead of Xubuntu 21.10

Tags: xubuntu, i3-wm

I am learning i3. I have installed i3 in Xubuntu 21.10 and selected i3 as window manager in login screen. I ran neofetch and it mentioned that OS is Ubuntu 21.10 instead of Xubuntu 21.10. Is this correct ?

Comment: Providing the output of what you see may help us understand, but if you're not using Xfce then the system being reported as Ubuntu 21.10 to me makes sense (the base of Ubuntu *flavors* is Ubuntu 21.10 **but without** `ubuntu-desktop`

Comment: All Ubuntu flavours and some Ubuntu based systems (like Mint e.g.) indentify themselves as Ubuntu. I make changes in Grub to indentify the difference in Kubuntu and Mint to make things easier for me.

Comment: Your question is misleading: your system is *not* "going" to Ubuntu, it is identifying itself as Ubuntu. Please update title of the question to reflect the question better.

Answer (score 0):

All comments are the answer to my question.

> Providing the output of what you see may help us understand, but if you're not using Xfce then the system being reported as Ubuntu 21.10 to me makes sense (the base of Ubuntu flavors is Ubuntu 21.10 but without ubuntu-desktop).

> All Ubuntu flavors and some Ubuntu based systems (like Mint e.g.) identify themselves as Ubuntu. I make changes in Grub to identify the difference in Kubuntu and Mint to make things easier for me.

> Your question is misleading: your system is not "going" to Ubuntu, it is identifying itself as Ubuntu.

Comment: Kind of a first-world problem, but you could always do: `neofetch --ascii_distro Xubuntu | sed 's/Ubuntu/Xubuntu/g'` instead.